# Timber - WordPress, Append data (json) to Timber\Post Object after ajax call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, twig, timber

**update 3**
Please see answer below!  Can provide further explanation there on request if needed

**Update 2**

js

```
 $archiveLayout.on('click',loadMoreButtonID,function(){


        let pageCount = $(this).attr('data-page'),
            nextPage  = parseInt( $(this).attr('data-page') ) + 1;



    let getParams;

    _.each($loadMoreButton, function(item) {
        let thisData = window.$(item).data()
        getParams = thisData;
    });

        console.log(getParams);

    $.post(ajaxurl, getParams,function(response){
            // var json_obj = JSON.parse(res);  
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);


        }).done(function(){

            $('#load-more').attr('data-page', nextPage);
        });

});
```

php function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_more_all_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_more_all_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_all_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_more_all_posts');
function ajax_more_all_posts()
{ 

    $response = array(
       'data' => Timber::compile(array('templates/blocks/content.twig'), $context)
    );
    wp_send_json($response);


}
```

HTML is retunred, but it's only 1 post and the data isn't populating the twig markup.

old****

So on my blog page, I want to load more posts, and I'm wondering if I can just append the response data to the **posts** array aleady on the page.  Or if need to build it out a certain way to allow for that.

Any tips/help etc would be greatly appreciated.

**code samples below**

I have the following set up in in my twig file:

```
{% for post in posts %}
            {% set postCount = loop.index %}    


            {% set postImage = TimberImage(post.get_field('preview_image_post'))|resize('medium_large') %}

            {% include "blocks/content.twig" with {post: post}  %}  

        {% endfor %}
```

Outputs the posts onto the page just fine.

I then make an ajax request doing the following:

```
window.axios.get(fancySquaresRestUrl + 'wp/v2/posts', {
            params: getParams
        })
        .then(function (response) {




          // append the entire repsonese? wasn't working, could be doing it wrong

            _.each( response.data, function( post, index ) {

                  //append each object on its own maybe???
            });




        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Isn't your response.data html?

Comment: @marciojc no it's json

Comment: If you're using ajax, then just use jQuery's `.append()` or `.after()`, if the data from ajax response is html...

Comment: What your AJAX request is returning? HTML? array of posts? array of Posts HTML? If JSON, you will need to render manually. Maybe returning the HTML can spare some time.

Comment: @RMH why dont you return HTML already render from the timber?

Comment: @marciojc how would you suggest doing that with twig templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer is as follows: (this is not appending anything to the Timber/Post Object, this is appending HTML from the data that get's passed to the twig file)

Any questions or comments you have about the below code feel free to ask.

The js used:

```
$archiveLayout.on('click',loadMoreButtonID,function(){


    var $this = $(this);

    var pageCount = $(this).attr('data-pageCount');
    var nextPage = parseInt($(this).attr('data-page')) + 1;

    var getParams = void 0;

    _.each($loadMoreButton, function (item) {
        var thisData = window.$(item).data();
        getParams = thisData;
    });
    getParams.pagecount = pageCount;
    // console.log(getParams);

    $loader.fadeIn();
    $loadMoreButton.fadeOut();
    $.post(ajaxurl, getParams, function (response) {
        // var json_obj = JSON.parse(res);  
        // console.log(response);
        //console.log(response.data);


        if(response === 'nomore'){
            $loadMoreButton.fadeOut();
        } else {
            for(var hp = 0; hp < response.length; hp++){
                $('[data-js="append-content"]').append(response[hp].data);
                $this.attr('data-pageCount', Number(pageCount)+1);
            }

            $loadMoreButton.fadeIn();
        }


    }).done(function () {
        $loader.fadeOut();
        // $('#load-more').attr('data-page', nextPage);
    });

});
```

the function being called:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_more_all_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_more_all_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_all_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_more_all_posts');
function ajax_more_all_posts()
{ 

$cat_id = $_REQUEST[ 'cat' ] or $_GET[ 'cat' ];
$paged = $_REQUEST['pagecount'];
$cat = $_REQUEST['dataCat'];



$args = [
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
];

if($paged != ""){
    $args['paged'] = $paged; 
}

$posts = Timber::get_posts($args);
$message = [];
if($posts){
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $response = array(
            'data' => Timber::compile('templates/blocks/content.twig', ['post' => $post])
        );
        $message[] = $response;
    }
} else {
    $message = "nomore";
}
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

wp_send_json($message);
die();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I already did something close. My solution was to render at the ajax and send the html.

So my Ajax calls a php and at the php I do this:

For this example my ajax call the `get_php_logic` action.
At the php action I do my logic to render the twig, at the final i return as Json response.

```
$response = array(
   'data' => Timber::compile(array('template.twig'), $context)
);
wp_send_json($response);
```

So this way my response.data will be html ready to append or replace.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you show me more of your example?

Comment: @RMH I update my aswner, also this will help you https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I can return HTML but the data inside the twig files isn't populated. 

In your php function are you running a for loop to past data to the rendered twig file?  

I've updated code to match what I have now.

Comment: @RMH yes insde my twig i'm looping the context data. Dont forget to populate your context variable with the information that you need.